# NSURLSession Implementation performance issue

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

My application having around 10 to 30 webservices(both get/post).previously i have used Async NSURLconnection. which takes around 5 sec to excute all services.  But now i have replaced NSurlsession which get delay in response compare to nsurlconnection ,it is delayed by 4 to 6 times . here i have attached one of the webservice method code for reference . like below i have code for all methods .

Example NSURLsession code

```
#pragma mark - NSURLSession

- (NSURLSession *)createSession
{
    NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: %s",__func__);

    static NSURLSession *session = nil;

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = WEBSERVICE_TIMEOUT;

    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig
                                            delegate:self
                                       delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    return session;
}


#pragma mark - API Callbacks
-(void)getMyData{
     @try {
        _webServieRequestType = HWDSCReturnGetRequestType;

        NSString *countrycode               =   [BusinessManager sharedInstance].countryCode;//[HWUserDefaults countryCode];
        NSString *userid                    =   [BusinessManager sharedInstance].userId;// [HWUserDefaults userId];
        NSString *accessToken               =   [BusinessManager sharedInstance].accessToken;//[HWUserDefaults accessToken];
        NSString *deviceId                  =   [HWUserDefaults deviceId];
        [HelperCallbacks logText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AccessToken %@",accessToken]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:API_DSCRETURN(countrycode,userid)]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
        [request setValue:deviceId forHTTPHeaderField:@"deviceId"];
        [request setValue:@"ba598025146eff37e26c9150b180a78b" forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-None-Match"];

        theSession = [self createSession];
        theDataTask = [theSession dataTaskWithRequest:request];

        [theDataTask resume];


    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [ExceptionHandler sendException:exception];
    }
}


#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDataDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: %s",__func__);

    //    NSArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


    if (theSession == session) {
        if (_receivedData == nil) {
            _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:data];
        } else {
            [_receivedData appendData:data];

        }
    }
    else
    {
        //NSLog(@"");
    }
     }

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: %s",__func__);


    if (theSession == session) {
        [BusinessManager sharedInstance].urlResponseRecieved = NO;
        NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: httpResponse:%@",response);
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        httpStatusCode =(int) [httpResponse statusCode]; // To track response Code:
        NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI : Http code:%d",httpStatusCode);
        NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI : Headers %@",[httpResponse allHeaderFields]);
        _receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];    }
       completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
     } 
#pragma mark - NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: %s",__func__);



    NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI: didFailWithError :error : %@ errorCode: %ld",error.description,(long)error.code);
    @try {

        if ([self.serviceDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ServiceMgrProtocol)] && [self.serviceDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webServiceDidFailDSCReturnWithError:)]&& error.code != 0) {
            [self.serviceDelegate webServiceDidFailDSCReturnWithError:error.localizedDescription];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"DSCReturnAPI:SUCCESS");
            [self processResponse];

        }

        }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [ExceptionHandler sendException:exception];
    }
    @finally {
        if (theSession) {
            theSession = nil;
        }
        _receivedData = nil;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to go for such methods of `NSURLSession` . It has its own block which runs on main thread.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestURL];

        NSLog(@"fetchAPromotionWithType = %@", requestURL);
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:
                                      ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                                      {

                                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                                              NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                                              int responseStatusCode = (int)[httpResponse statusCode];

                                              if ( responseStatusCode == OK_RESPONSE_CODE || responseStatusCode == CREATED_RESPONSE_CODE || responseStatusCode == ACCEPTED_RESPONSE_CODE || responseStatusCode == PARTIAL_RESPONSE_CODE)
                                              {
                                                  if (data)
                                                  {
                                                      NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                                      NSLog(@"Data->%@",dict);

                                                      if (dict != nil && [dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                                                      {
                                                          NSDictionary *dataDict = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];

                                                          if (dataDict != nil && [dataDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                                                          {
                                                              //Get your success Data
                                                          }
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  if (responseStatusCode == 0)
                                                  {
                                                      NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"No Connection! Please try again.", @"message", nil];
                                                      //Get Your Fail Data
                                                  }
                                                  else if (data)
                                                  {
                                                      // NSArray *tempArray = @[@"fan", @"vungle"];
                                                      //[JLSharedData sharedManager].savedWaterfallInterstitialArray = nil; //testing

                                                      NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                                      //Get Your Fail Data
                                                  }
                                              }

                                          });

                                      }];

        [task resume];
    }];
```

Comment: hi i have tried that also which also delay in response

Comment: Then that must be some clean up needed from server side, Try to clear cache and server memory increase. Because NSURLSession is only one in morden Cocoa touch that gives very fast and reliable response more than AFNetWorking  :)

Comment: i have checked with the server ppl ,they are sure about cache  and they don't have any cache there . so simply restarted but no change